# AWS EKS Group NLB as ALB but with different ports

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, ingress-controller

To define a VPC Link into API Gateway we have to declare an NLB in eks (LoadBalancer service) to access the pod in the VPC.

When we define ingress resource, we can group them into one ALB with the annotation `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name`

It seems not possible to do the same with multiple service as a network load balancer. Is it possible ? Or just a bad idea to expose multiple micro-service (with different endpoint) on the same NLB with port as discriminant ?

Comment: Are you using the ALB Ingress controller(v1) or the AWS LB Ingress controller(v2)?

Comment: I'm using the v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: Not possible as of today

AWS LB ingress controller supports ALB and NLB, but keep in mind that the ALB ingress controller:

- watches the `Ingress` objects with `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/*` annotations for ALB
- also watches `Service` objects with `service.beta.kubernetes.io/*` annotations for NLB

As of I am writing this, there are no annotations under service.beta.kubernetes.io/* that implements want you need.

Comment: see this open issue: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2234#issuecomment-923177448 please throw a thumbup(I already did) as I think this is a very reasonable feature.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will thumb up.